# InteropServices.COMException when running WatiN tests

Tags: nunit, watin

When I run WatiN tests on our build server they all throw this InteropServices.COMException:

MyTestClassName.MyTestMethodName:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80004005.

I get the same result wether I run them through TeamCity or I run them manually on the server as an administrator using NUnit GUI (2.5).

This is some sample code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTestClassName
{
    private string pageUrl;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetUp()
    {
        pageUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteURL"] + "/Pages/MyPage.aspx";

        Settings.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
    }

    [Test]
    public void MyTestMethodName()
    {
        using (var ie = new IE(pageUrl))
        {
            ie.SelectList(new Regex(@"^*DropDownList1*$")).Option("TheOption").Select();

            ie.SelectList(new Regex(@"^*DropDownList2*$")).Option("AnOption").Select();

            ie.SelectList(new Regex(@"^*DropDownList3*$")).Option("OtherOption").Select();

        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what it can be?

/Joakim

Answer (score 6):

Try running Visual Studio as Administrator.

Answer (score 5):

I also meet the same problem but more strange for me.

I've got a server only for "UI testing" and for many application de WatiN test runs without any problem.

This error only happens for one application and only in CruiseControl (with nant) but not when runing the test with NUnitGUI...

I Finnaly found a solution this morning: I replaced all my call `new IE();` to `new IE(true)` [WatiN release note](http://watin.sourceforge.net/releasenotes-1-2-0-4000.html) And didn't get the error anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Another fix is to "Enable Protected mode in IE" like described [here](http://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/234-watin-tests-fail-with-comexceptions-and-other-errors-fix/)

Answer (score 2):

Every time IE.Quit was called by WatiN IE would stop responding and then try to recover. Run as admin fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

[Another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939287/interopservices-comexception-when-running-watin-tests/1702169#1702169) says:

> Try running Visual Studio as Administrator

It is actually NUnit that needs to be run as administrator (at least in Windows 7), but the thinking is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the select list is not yet fully loaded and ready, and this is another symptom of the same problem described in this question:

[Access denied error ( Visual Studio and WatiN )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959150/access-is-denied-error/)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not - all our WatiN tests fail with the same Exception.